# Apache ignite Work directory path must be absolute

Tags: ignite

I am trying to store a few csv files in apache ignites file system but the issue is I can not even run the program as it gives me an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Work directory path must be absolute: files
```

This is how I configured the working directory:

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();

DataRegionConfiguration dataRegionCfg = new DataRegionConfiguration();

dataRegionCfg.setInitialSize(1073741824L);
dataRegionCfg.setMaxSize(21474836480L);

dataStorageCfg.setDefaultDataRegionConfiguration(dataRegionCfg);

cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageCfg);

cfg.setWorkDirectory("files");
cfg.setIgniteHome("home");
```

I am using Eclipse and Maven for my program

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, your work and home directory need to be *absolute* rather than *relative*:

```
cfg.setWorkDirectory("/home/ignite/files");
cfg.setIgniteHome("/home/ignite");
```

Comment: I have updated the paths as you mentioned and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using Windows or a Mac? Either the error message changed, or it doesn't recognise the values you supplied as an absolute path.

Comment: I am using Windows. Error message is the same : Work directory path must be absolute: \home\ignite\files.

Comment: try `c:\home\ignite\files`

Comment: I used :  `C://home/ignite/files` This created the directories in C but it gives me a new error: `ProductLicenseException [shortMsg=Invalid X509 certificate.]`

Comment: That’s not an issue with Ignite. It’s open source, so there’s no product licence file that could be invalid. This could be your OS or maybe your JVM is out of date or needs reconfiguring.